# asp button clicked as default

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, imagebutton

I'm working with asp classic, I have 2 form, the form1 has a button, if the user pressed it goes to the form2, and have to press another button called "consultar", but I want that pressing the first button, goes to the action of form2 without press the 2nd. button "consultar", I've tried onClick event, but doesn´t works, I need that button act as pressed and show something like been already pressed.can you help me? there is a javascript function for this?
here is my code:

```
<a href="index.asp?ia=100&r=g"  onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" 
onmouseover="MM_swapImage('selector_r3_c2','','img/selector_r3_c2_s2.png',1);" >
<img name="selector_r3_c2" src="img/selector_r3_c2.png" width="168" height="55" 
id="selector_r3_c2" alt="" /></a>
<input name="btConsultar" type="hidden" value="Consultar" onkeypress="Selected"  /></td>
```

Comment: Can you illustrate better - the code you're showing doesn't relate well to your description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about javascript but you should be able to do something with classic asp and form variables and logical statements.  eg form 1 could have a hidden attribute

```
<input type="hidden" name="buttonpressed" value="1" />
```

Then you could have an image button in form 2 as follows

```
<%  if request.form("buttonpressed") = 1 then
    submitbutton = "pressed.gif"
    else
    submitbutton = "unpressed.gif"
    End If %>

<input type="image" src="<%=submitbutton%>" name="Consultar" />
```